# Best practice on initializing your NSStrings on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, nsstring, analyzer

xCode's "build and analyze" complains about "s" being possible garbage.

Which is the better solution?  A, B, or C?

```
NSString *s;              // A
NSString *s = nil;        // B
NSString *s = @"";        // C

if(x == 1) s = @"you picked 1";
if(x == 2) s = @"you picked 2";
if(x == 3) s = @"you picked 3";
```

Answer (score 2):

I always go with

```
NSString *s = nil;
```

as a default initialization value. It's more sensible than an empty string (an empty string is a "thing", whereas `nil` is an unknown value), and since you can message `nil` in Objective-C it (generally) doesn't cause big problems if I somehow forget to give it a "real" value.

Comment: nil is not unknown, it is very well defined. The empty string on the other hand also (probably) allocates memory. nil is the way to go.

Comment: I mean to say that `nil` represents an unknown value, whereas an empty string is a known value.

Comment: What will be the 'value' of `s` when initializing it like `NSString *s;` ? Will it just be `nil`, like with ivars that haven't been manually assigned a value, or will it be something else?

Comment: It'll be garbage. In Obj-C, instance vars are automatically initialized to `nil`, but local vars point at areas of memory that likely have no meaningful values.

Comment: Sounds like "set it to nil" is the way to go.  Does that also apply for NSMutableString used in the same way as above?